# Meaning of "For donkey's ears?"

Tags: meaning

While recently reading an article I stumbled upon this phrase. From the context of the article, I cannot find the definition of this phrase as most results are irrelevant. Answers?

Comment: It's Cockney rhyming slang: *donkey's ears* == *donkey's **years*** == ***years*** == a long time. You can google it for more details.

Comment: _Donkey's years_ is practically indistinguishable from _donkey's ears_ in speech. /y/ normally merges when it occurs before or after /i/ at speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/donkey's+years):

> **donkey's years** A long time, as in I haven't seen her in donkey's years. This expression punningly alludes to the considerable length of
>   the animal's ears.

Also you might want to read [this](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/donkeys-years.html) and [this](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/donkey%27s_ears).